# Can't run packages with latest distribution?

Tags: ros, catkin-package, build, build-package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have now the Indigo ROS distribution, latest one until the time of writing (with Ubuntu 14.04). When I go in a package (on the ROS wiki) I can only use it with the distributions that it has under it's name (with the blue buttons) or is that only the documentation? For example if in a package it says only Groovy and Hydro, can I use it in Indigo?

If I can't do that, I remember reading that I can have multiple distributions in my computer (at least if I use the **catkin** file system). So I can have "groovy" and "indigo" ?

Can I also create a package using packages from different distributions? If yes, how do I do it using the catkin method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191405/can%27t-run-packages-with-latest-distribution?/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The distributions listed on the wiki are only for documentation. Packages may also work on other distributions, but a lack of documentation indicates that they probably haven't been tested.

The changes between Indigo and Hydro are fairly small, so most packages that worked in Hydro should work in Indigo.

Indigo is still fairly new, so it's quite likely that the package maintainer simply hasn't had time or resources to test their package on Indigo yet. If you do find a package that works on Indigo but isn't documented yet, it might be nice to let the maintainer know so that they can update the documentation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2